# Retrieving the custom background images on wp7 on start up

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have added a button(**BackgroundBrowser**) to change the background of my app randomly. But when i exit and relaunch the app, the last image that has been set by the user is not same as the current background image. I don't know how to retrieve the last image that is set in my app and make it as the current background image. Below is the codes i have used to change the backgrounds randomly.

```
private void BackgroundBrowser_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string imguri = "";

        click_count = click_count % 5;
        switch (click_count)
        {
            case 0: imguri = "Image/bg.jpg"; break;
            case 1: imguri = "Image/bg1.jpg"; break;
            case 2: imguri = "Image/bg3.jpg"; break;
            case 3: imguri = "Image/bg2.jpg"; break;
            case 4: imguri = ""; break;
        }
        click_count++;

        var app = Application.Current as App;
        app.appBmp = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imguri, UriKind.Relative));
        ImageBrush imageBrush = new ImageBrush();
        imageBrush.Stretch = Stretch.UniformToFill;
        imageBrush.Opacity = 0.7;
        imageBrush.ImageSource = app.appBmp;
        this.LayoutRoot.Background = imageBrush;
        app.appbrush = imageBrush;
        app.backchanged = true;
    }
```

Can anybody help with this? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Just save it in the Isolated Storage. For example, save the uri string ("Images/bg.jpg") and then when you restart your app, check if there's a value in the IsolatedStorage, read it and then set the background accordingly.

[Isolated Storage](http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2010/10/15/31-days-of-windows-phone-day-15-isolated-storage/)